# JavaScript: How to pull out a string from a URL using a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, url

In java, I have this URL as a string:

```
window.location.href = 
"http://localhost:8080/bladdey/shop/c6c8262a-bfd0-4ea3-aa6e-d466a28f875/hired-3";
```

I want to create a javascript regular expression to pull out the following string:

```
c6c8262a-bfd0-4ea3-aa6e-d466a28f875
```

To find left hand marker for the text, I could use the regex:

```
window\.location\.href \= \"http\:\/\/localhost:8080\/bladdey\/shop\/
```

However, I don't know how to get to the text between that and `/hired3"`

What is the best way to pull out that string from a URL using javascript?

Comment: is the base fixed and the end always like `/*`?

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string in tokens and look for a string that has 4 occurrences of `-`.

Or, if the base is always the same, you could use the following code:

```
String myString = window.location.href;
myString = myString.substring("http://localhost:8080/bladdey/shop/".Length());
myString = myString.subString(0, myString.indexOf('/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookahead and a lookbehind,

```
(?<=http://localhost:8080/bladdey/shop/).+?(?=/hired3)
```

Check [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more information.

Also, there is no need to escape the `:` or `/` characters.

Comment: does not compile. I get: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \
 \ )

Comment: Sorry, I copied your text for the first part of the regex. Like I said in the last part, there is no need to escape `:` or `/`. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [capturing groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) to pull out some content of your string.
In your case :

```
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(http://localhost:8080/bladdey/shop/)(.+)(/hired-3)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    if(matcher.matches()){
       String value = matcher.group(2);
    }
```

Comment: how come you don't need to escape anything there?

Comment: @BreakoBreako There is no need to add escape characters in this case. You can try it, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need a regex, and some way to use it...

```
  String theLocation = "http://localhost:8080/bladdey/shop/c6c8262a-bfd0-4ea3-aa6e-d466a28f8752/hired-3";
  String pattern = "(?</bladdey/shop/).+?(?=/hired3)";

  // Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
  } else {
     System.out.println("NO MATCH");
  }
```

note - this will still work when you change the host (it only looks for `bladdey/shop/`)

Comment: does not compile. I get: invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: Ah... I hate it when I get those wrong. Too many differences between different platforms. Since it didn't like my `\/` I just took them out - apparently forward slashes are OK, only the backslash needs escaping. I think it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

```
String param = html.replaceFist("(?s)^.*http://localhost:8080/bladdey/shop/([^/]+)/hired-3.*$", "$1");

if (param.equals(html)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Not found");
}
UUID uuid = new UUID(param);
```

In regex:

- `(?s)` let the `.` char wildcard also match newline characters.
- `^` begin of text
- `$` end of text
- `.*` zero or more (*) any (.) characters
- `[^...]+` one or more (+) of characters not (^) being ...

Between the first parentheses substitutes `$1`.

Comment: Thanks but it does not include the hired-3 part.

Comment: Actually the regex `([^/]+)/` means any sequence of characters that is not a forward slash, and is followed by a forward slash, is also valid.

Comment: @BreakoBreako added forgotten hired-3.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to pull out GUID from anything:

```
var regex = /[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{11,12}/i
```

It should really be `{12}` but in your url it is malformed and has just 15.5 bytes of information.